# shared preferences values are showing again when application relauncehes

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have two activities ..in first Loginactivity if button click then am storing values in sahred prefrences and in second activtty that is (Firstscreen i ahve button logout if i click on that then renmoving stored sharedpreferences values...

....after exiting the application and relaunces application then if i print then Shared preferences stored values are printing...(if i logout then completely remove the values )

```
public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


 User myApplication;

    EditText username,passwordField;
    Button login;
    CheckBox check;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    String userStored;
    String passwordStored;
     boolean checked =false;
     boolean checkboxvalue;
     public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);




login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub




        //  settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());


                settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);               
                editor = settings.edit();                                   
                editor.putString("User_Shared", username.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Pass_Shared", passwordField.getText().toString());                
                //editor.putBoolean("Checkbox_Click", true);

                editor.commit();

                userStored = settings.getString("User_Shared",null);
                passwordStored =settings.getString("Pass_Shared", null);                     


                System.out.println("userStored :::" +userStored + " :::::::pasword :::::::" +passwordStored  );

                 Intent intent =  new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstScreen.class);
                 startActivity(intent);

            }   


    }
});



}
}           





public class FirstScreen extends Activity {


    Button logout;

    SharedPreferences settings;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "Shared_File";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.firstscreen);




  logout =(Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);

  logout.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    //  settings = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()); 

        settings =getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();   

           try {

               editor.remove("User_Shared");
               editor.remove("Pass_Shared");


                   editor.clear();
               editor.commit();
        }

           catch (NullPointerException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
           catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 


    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            //intent.putExtra("Logout", logout);

        startActivity(intent);



    }
});



}
}
```

Comment: Shared Preferences are meant to persist data, and will not be removed unless you manually do so.

Comment: What is the Logcat output?

Comment: yeah... if i logout hten it has to be removed permanantly...

Comment: kiran and 123456 assume ...if i login with this values and logout then the fields has to be null ..if again i reopen app the am getting kiran and 123456.....it has to be null

Comment: Values will only be erased if logout is pressed else it will hold values even you restart your application.
You may erase values in onStop() method of Activity.

Comment: yeah i has to be logout....so values to be erased and relaunche then erased values will be dispalyed..

Comment: that is null but am getting values...

Answer (score 0):

This is related to activity life cycle. You should put the code related to SharedPreferences in onPause method. The fault with your code is that it is storing the key values pairs in the SharedPreferences object but that gets erased when you press back button or if the activity comes out of its active state. 
So, try my suggestion. Good luck dude. Hope, it was beneficial.

Answer (score 0):

Very easy for you to put

```
editor.putString("User_Shared", null);
```

And everything will work fine.

Comment: i have to store the user entered values when login and when logout i have to remove...

Comment: I know: when login you already put that code editor.putString("User_Shared", username.getText().toString());
                editor.putString("Pass_Shared", passwordField.getText().toString()); Now when you click on LogOut button put null inside the sharedpref and the next time you open the app you check for null in credentials, and if it is will be null just bring the user to login screen